# Update shape color using Ruby Google Slides API

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-api-client, google-slides-api, google-slides

I'm trying to update an ellipsis shape using the google slides api in ruby. This is the code:

```
shape_properties = {
    shape_background_fill: {
        solid_fill: {
            color: {
                rgb_color: {
                    red: 1.0,
                    green: 0,
                    blue: 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

requests = [{
              update_shape_properties: {
                object_id: ellipse.object_id,
                fields: 'shapeBackgroundFill',
                shape_properties: shape_properties,
              },
            }]

# Execute the request.
req = Google::Apis::SlidesV1::BatchUpdatePresentationRequest.new(requests: requests)
response = @slides.batch_update_presentation(presentation_id,req)
```

Another code that I've tried with the same error is this one:

```
rgb_color = Google::Apis::SlidesV1::RgbColor.new(red: 1.0, green: 0, blue: 0)
color = Google::Apis::SlidesV1::OpaqueColor.new(rgb_color: rgb_color)
solid_fill = Google::Apis::SlidesV1::SolidFill.new(color: color)
shape_background_fill = Google::Apis::SlidesV1::ShapeBackgroundFill.new(solid_fill: solid_fill)
shape_properties = Google::Apis::SlidesV1::ShapeProperties.new(shape_background_fill: shape_background_fill)
requests = [{
                update_shape_properties: {
                  object_id: ellipse.object_id,
                  fields: 'shapeBackgroundFill',
                  shape_properties: shape_properties,
                },
            }]
req = Google::Apis::SlidesV1::BatchUpdatePresentationRequest.new(requests: requests)
response = @slides.batch_update_presentation(presentation_id, req)
```

I get this error:

```
`check_status': badRequest: Invalid requests[0].updateShapeProperties: The object () could not be found. (Google::Apis::ClientError)
```

Any idea why is it fails?

Comment: **The object () could not be found.** sounds like your not sending an object

Comment: @DaImTo I've updated the post with another try that I did to make sure I was sending an object, but I had the same error

Answer (score 0):

try using `object_id_prop` instead of `object_id` in update_shape_properties.

```
shape_properties = {
    shape_background_fill: {
        solid_fill: {
            color: {
                rgb_color: {
                    red: 1.0,
                    green: 0,
                    blue: 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

requests = [{
          update_shape_properties: {
            object_id_prop: ellipse.object_id,
            fields: 'shapeBackgroundFill',
            shape_properties: shape_properties,
          },
        }]

# Execute the request.
req = Google::Apis::SlidesV1::BatchUpdatePresentationRequest.new(requests: 
requests)
response = @slides.batch_update_presentation(pres`entation_id,req)
```

Because UpdateShapePropertiesRequest has [object_id_prop](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/generated/google/apis/slides_v1/classes.rb#L4686) accessor instead of `object_id`.
That's why [object_id](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Object.html#method-i-object_id) name is already used in Object.